# Correct path to file in LiteSpeed web server on Linux

Tags: php, linux, include-path, litespeed

I have the following PHP script placed in the root directory of my web hosting server, and it works fine.

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/init.php');
```

When I moved the script to a new folder under my web root, i.e. `public_html/myfolder`, the script gives the following error:

```
Warning: include(/home/name/public_html/folder/config/config.inc.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/name/public_html/folder/test.php on line 2

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/name/public_html/folder/config/config.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/name/public_html/folder/test.php on line 2

Warning: require_once(/home/name/public_html/folder/init.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/name/public_html/folder/test.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/name/public_html/folder/init.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/name/public_html/folder/test.php on line 3
```

Should I change the path as follows:

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../init.php');
```

Am I correct?

Comment: I bet it would be easier to try it yourself. Anyway, where are those files required for include? When you include something, you only have to check that the included file is truly there :)

Comment: It work, but I want to be sure I'm correct. The files are in: `public_html/config/config.inc.php` and
`public_html/init.php`

Comment: What does `echo dirname(__FILE__);` output to you?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, you say you only moved your script (the one that contains the `include` lines) to the "public_html/folder". That way, `dirname(__FILE__)` contains the full path, including the "folder" directory. So, now, you need to go up one step in the directory tree, to be able to reach the "config" directory; an explanation follows:

Before you had:

```
/home/name/public_html/config/config.inc.php
/home/name/public_html/init.php
```

So your file

```
/home/name/public_html/test.php
```

Managed to access the files using the path from `dirname(__FILE)`. But now, the test.php has been movedto the directory "folder":

```
/home/name/public_html/folder/test.php
```

Thus, `dirname(__FILE__)` should return the path comprehensive of the "folder" directory. But the files you need to include are in teh "old" directory, so youneed to add that `../` to the path of the include, to be abletoreach those files :)

Comment: `echo dirname(__FILE__);` outputs from root directory /public_html: `/home/name/public_html` and from public_html/folder: `/home/name/public_html/folder`. So should I use the path I mentined above or this: `include(dirname(__FILE__).'../config/config.inc.php');` `require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../init.php');`?

Comment: Sure, and i gave the explanation of this in my answer. Let me know if it's not clear :)

Comment: To add that `../` **before** the slash or **inside** the slash, i.e. which one is correct, Nr 1) or Nr 2)? 1)`require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../init.php');`  2)`require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../init.php');`

Comment: The slash should be given, as you do in `include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');`: in fact, the `..` is nothing more than a directory, just like "config" or "folder". Same rules apply :)